# MRIcro not running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, software-installation

I did a normal installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit last week, and then installed [MRIcro](http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/mricro/mricro/linux.html)

But it just cannot run, with the error

```
/usr/local/bin/mricro/mribin: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/bin/mricro/mribin: undefined symbol: initPAnsiStrings
```

My machine is 64-bit, but I'm not sure the author's [instruction](http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/mricro/mricro/linux64.txt) applies to my situation or not. I googled for a while but found very few related info.

I remember MRIcro runs smoothly on old Ubuntu, like 11? can't remember the exact version number.

Does anyone have similar problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had to run the following to make it work:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libjpeg62:i386
```

Then  edit `/usr/local/bin/startmricro64` to

```
export GCONV_PATH=/usr/lib32/gconv
```

and you should be able to run it by `/usr/local/bin/startmricro64`.

Answer (score 0):

I have met same situation in Ubuntu 12.04LTS installed to 64-bit system. 
After installation of `libjpeg62:i386` package, it was solved and
MRIcro was run normally.

Answer (score -2):

On 64bit systems, after you install **libjpeg62:i386**, you may have some other missing libraries.

in my case: 
ldd mricro/libborqt-6.9-qt2.3.so 
.... 
libSM.so.6 => not found 
libICE.so.6 => not found 
...

for these you need to install **ia32-libs** through: 
sudo -i 
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe 
multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list  
apt-get update 
apt-get install ia32-libs 
sudo ldconfig

Comment: ia32-libs is no longer supported on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. ***Installing it can break your system.*** It was replaced by the `multiarch` mechanism.